# Сколько существует двоичных чисел длины n , таких, что в их записи количество единиц больше количества нулей?

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
ans = 1                       # начиная со случая где вообще нет 0, а просто 1
for i in range(1,(n+1)//2):   # i - это нули
    ans +=(n- 1 - i) * i + 1  #взять число, убрав нули и самую первую цифру(тоесть 1, т.к. числа с начинающиеся с нуля не считаются) и умножить на количество нулей, рассмотрев тем самым все возможные перемещения нулей

print(ans)
```

не проходит и нескольких тестов
я налажал с формулой, с количеством итераций или с чем еще?

Comment: Кажется в формуле где-то должны быть биномиальные коэффициенты.

Comment: Не заметил условие, что числа начинающиеся с нуля не считаются. Пишите условия задачи не в коде.

Answer (score 3):

если не путаю, то решение в лоб будет выглядеть так:

```
res = 0

for i in range(math.floor(1 + n / 2), n + 1):
    res += math.factorial(n) // (math.factorial(i) * math.factorial(n - i))

print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы узнать, сколькими способами можно получить `k` элементов (в нашем случае единиц) из `n` элементов (в нашем случае полная длинна) используются [сочетания](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). А конкретно, нас интересует, сколькими способами можно выбрать `k` элементов из `n`-элементного множества. Для этого используется формула C<sup>k</sup><sub>n</sub>.

```py
import math

def c_n_k(n, k):
    """
    Получение количества сочетаний k элементов из n-элементного множества
    """
    return math.factorial(n) // (math.factorial(k) * math.factorial(n - k))

n = int(input())  # Длина двоичного числа

minimum_ones = math.floor(n / 2) + 1  # Минимальное количество единиц, чтобы удовлетворялось условие

ans = 0

for ones_count in range(minimum_ones, n + 1):  # Перебираем количество единиц, начиная от минимума до полной длины
    ans += c_n_k(n, ones_count)  # Прибавляем количество чисел, в которых ones_count единиц
```

Последние 3 строки можно написать в одну, используя функцию [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```py
ans = sum(map(lambda x: c_n_k(n, x), range(minimum_ones, n + 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю можно решить быстрее без цикла суммирования:

```py
import math

def binomial(a, b):
    return math.factorial(a) // (math.factorial(b) * math.factorial(a - b))

n = int(input())
if n > 1:
    c = 2 ** (n - 2) + (n % 2) * binomial(n - 1, (n - 1) // 2) // 2
elif n == 1:
    c = 1
else:
    c = 0
```

Числа начинающиеся с нуля не учитываются.

Comment: Идея правильная, в формуле "скользкая" ошибка  `c = 2 ** (n - 1) + (binomial(n, n // 2) // 2 if (n+1)%2 else 0)`

Comment: не знаю, то что вы дали не выдает правильные ответы. А что такое "скользкая" ошибка?

Comment: 1,1,3,4,11,16,42   http://oeis.org/A027306  Про "скользкую" ошибку -  это я зря написал - пытался преобразовать формулу разными способами.

Comment: Да, я сразу нашел эту последовательность на этом сайте. )

Comment: @MBo, ... хотя нет, я нашел сразу другую ссылку https://oeis.org/A058622 . `a(n) is the number of n-digit binary sequences that have more 1's than 0's. - Geoffrey Critzer, Jul 16 2009`

Comment: Эта последовательность не требует ведущей единицы  (у автора `(тоесть 1, т.к. числа с начинающиеся с нуля не считаются)`)

Comment: Эта последовательность отличается от той, что вы дали только знаком минус в формуле.

Comment: Да, и смещением на 1 (A027306: `of length n+1`)

Comment: при n>0 формула работает.

Comment: Случай 5 цифр: `11111, 11110, 11101, 11011, 10111, 11100, 11010, 11001, 10110, 10101, 10011`- **11** вариантов. Есть такое число в Вашей последовательности?

Comment: Вы не посчитали числа начинающиеся с 0.

Comment: Я же привёл цитату автора, что ему нужно только с 1

Comment: @MBo, спасибо за уточнение, обновил ответ.